# Derived field in object types

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-workshop, foundry-actions

Is there any way to populate a field based on other field (basically getting a substring) in ontology object type through actions/workshop or ontology itself?

I know we can do it through function based action but don't want to use that for only 1 field.